# I'm looking for an outline of the practices going from beginner to jhana or streamentry

Tags: theravada, meditation-recommendation

I'm looking for something similar to this little book, [The
Basic
Method
of
Meditation](https://bswa.org/bswp/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/ajahn-brahm_the-basic-method-of-meditation.pdf) (10~20 pages) from Ajahn Brahm.

Or something like this -- [Meditation:
What is taught and practised in Pa-Auk.](https://www.paaukforestmonastery.org/meditation)

Personally, I would need it to be Theravada and preferably be on the gentle side (unlike Brahm and Pa Auk which are pretty strict).

But mainly what the title says: an outline of the practices going from beginner to jhana or streamentry.

Comment: So you are looking for something simpler and more concise than those two links? But more clear than the outline suttas?

Comment: Theravāda is strict from the past to the future. PaAuk's path is very relax and easy  when comparing to self reading the Tipitaka and Atthakatha. Every rule is protecting the practitioner from the risk. **The easy way is Samatha. Theravāda is teaching Vipassanā which is harder than Samatha**.

Comment: @Bonn. I was going to write that too, that Ven. Pa-Auk Sayadaw's approach and teaching is gentle and relaxed yet firm but I wouldn't call it strict. It's a great beginner-to-advanced way of practicing the Jhanas.

Comment: Check https://www.dhammatalks.org/suttas/AN/AN11_2.html and https://www.dhammatalks.org/suttas/AN/AN8_70.html

Comment: This one would serve as a more detailed answer: https://www.dhammatalks.org/suttas/MN/MN39.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an authentic guide on early Buddhist meditation (Ajahn Brahm and Pa Auk teach meditation practices that are completely different, based on Vism. and late Buddhist redefinitions of jhana), here are two great books:

Thanissaro Bhikkhu's books and articles on dhammatalks.org, especially "With Each and Every Breath"
Bhante Henepola Gunaratana
Beyond Mindfulness in Plain English, 2010 CE (from wisdom pub). The book is more broadly based on EBT Jhāna. 16 APS is one of the methods he discusses, but does not focus in detail on the 16 steps.

Answer (score 1):

Observing five precepts is the shortest way to enter the path. Then read the following.

[A Study Guide on the First Stage of Awakening](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/study/into_the_stream.html#practice)

OR

[Buddhism Course](http://www.urbandharma.org/pdf/PDF_BuddhismCourse) by Chan Khoon San (take about 12 hours to read and give you a good idea about the teaching)